# If $A^2=B^2$ and $A$ is invertible, show that $B$ is invertible and find $B^{-1}$ (in terms of $A^{-1}$, $A$ and $B$)

Tags: linear-algebra

So we know that $AA^{-1} =I$ and $A^{-1}A=I$. So we multiply both sides of the inequality by $(A^{-1})^{2}$ from the right in case(1), left case(2) and multiply by $A^{-1}$ from left and right in case(3).
We get $I = B^2(A^{-1})^{2} = (A^{-1})^{2}B^2 = A^{-1}B^2A^{-1}$

You can say that B is invertible as there exists a matrix $X= B$    $(A^{-1})^{2} = (A^{-1})^{2}B$ s.t $BX=I$ but $XB$ should also hold so there's still a bit of confusion.

Not sure if that's enough but finding $B^{-1}$ seemed to pose a bit of a problem. I suspected hat $B^{-1}=A^{-1}$ but I don't have enough evidence.

Comment: you can use determinant for invertibility.

Comment: You actually found $B^{-1}$. It is indeed $X = B(A^{-1})^2 = (A^{-1})^2 B$.

Comment: Please see my edits.  You DO NOT NEED the number of dollar signs you used in formatting, but I appreciate the attempt to format.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new to the whole LaTeX thing, I'll tone down on the edits

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, they're much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In matrices of finite size if $XY=I$ then $YX=I$. So $BA^{-2} 
$ is the inverse of $B$.

The last phrase in the OP is false: take $A=I, B=-I$.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2):

The inverse of $\;B\;$ is $\;B\left(A^{-1}\right)^2\;,\;$ indeed it results that

$B\cdot B\left(A^{-1}\right)^2=B^2\left(A^{-1}\right)^2=A^2\left(A^{-1}\right)^2=I$

and

$B\left(A^{-1}\right)^2\cdot B=\left(A^{-1}\right)^2\cdot A^2\cdot B\left(A^{-1}\right)^2\cdot B=$

$=\left(A^{-1}\right)^2\cdot B^2\cdot B\left(A^{-1}\right)^2\cdot B=\left(A^{-1}\right)^2\cdot B\cdot B^2\left(A^{-1}\right)^2\cdot B=$

$=\left(A^{-1}\right)^2\cdot B\cdot A^2\left(A^{-1}\right)^2\cdot B=$

$=\left(A^{-1}\right)^2\cdot B^2=\left(A^{-1}\right)^2\cdot A^2=I\;.$

In general it is false that $\;B^{-1}=A^{-1}\;$.

Here is a counterexample.

$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&1\end{bmatrix}\;,\quad B=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}.$

$A^2=B^2=\begin{bmatrix}5&4\\4&5\end{bmatrix},\;$ but

$A^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{3}\begin{bmatrix}-1&2\\2&-1\end{bmatrix}\ne\dfrac{1}{3}\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\-1&2\end{bmatrix}=B^{-1}.$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, real helpful!